# Is there an eclipse plugin that runs google's cpplint.py on open files?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I would love to be able to run `cpplint.py` from within Eclipse so that I can find the places where I am making incorrect styling decisions (according to the Google style guide at least)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know `cpplint.py`, but you should be able to run any tool from within Eclipse as an "external tool".

See under `Run >> Externals Tools`

The arguments can even be [parameterized](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fconcepts-exttools.htm) so you can include the path of the current project or similar. The output is placed in a console view and if the messages from the tool is anything like those from other tools (e.g. "file:line:message"), you should even have hyperlinks from the out to the relevant files.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this http://wangzw.github.io/CppStyle/
It is an eclipse plugin that run cpplint.py on save. It also add clang-format as another c/c++ code formatter.